# How to use DFS on an array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, depth-first-search

I have a 1 dimensional list of values, it looks like this "int[] values'".  I beleive I have converted it to a 2d list like this  :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        board[i][j] = values[i * 4 + j];
    }
}
```

The board is the new 2 dimensional list of values. On the board there are numbers.  A 0 means an empty space, a 1 is a green, a 2 is a blue, and a 3 is a red.  How would I use depth first search to find a completed path of a certain color?

Comment: Describe the algorithm you would use in English first .. then worry about converting that description to Java.  (Homework question, so no code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make a 2D array `boolean[][] visited` designating the points that you have visited; set all elements to `false`
- Go through each point in two nested loops
- For each point where `visited[r][c]` is `false`, go into a DFS which you can implement recursively
- Inside the recursive DFS call check if the point is your destination; if yes, return `true`
- If the point has the correct color, explore its neighbors (up to four) in four directions
- If a neighbor has the right color, mark it as visited, and make a recursive call
- If a recursive call returns `true`, return true
- Otherwise, continue exploring other neighbors
- Once you are done exploring neighbors, return `false`.

Comment: Alright thank you, this makes sense.  But I guess I should have been more specific in my question, but I'm not too sure on how to actually do a dfs on the array.  Is like a regular one? Or does it need to be modified since its on an array?

Comment: @user2835532 Think of an array as of an implicit representation of a graph. Each element is a vertex, with up to four edges connecting it to its neighbors (corners have two edges; sides have three edges; cells in the middle have all four). This gives you a complete representation of a graph.